# ADFS Authentication using PHP

Tags: php, sharepoint, adfs, ws-trust

I'm not friendly with Microsoft's architecture but I have to implement an ADFS Authenfication on a website.

I decided to use WS-Trust to solve it.

So first, I send a RST (Request Security Token) to http://server.com//adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed

I receive the excepted RSTS (Request Security Token Response) which contains the security token.

But, I'm stuck, I don't know what to do next.

The main goal is to be logged to a SharePoint website which is require ADFS authentication.

Maybe, someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can POST the RSTR to the `_trust` endpoint on the Sharepoint server and get back a `fedauth` cookie that you'd present on subsequent calls to Sharepoint. This is shown in sample PHP code here: https://github.com/zandbelt/php-ws-trust-client/blob/master/sharepoint/login.php